# Cannot modify, create files/ folder in HDD with Ubuntu and Windows running on same SSD in PC

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, time

To introduce myself, I'm new to Linux and have a passion to work with Linux rather than Windows10.

I bought a New-PC Pre-installed with Windows 10 on SSD. Installed Ubuntu to the same SSD as Dual Boot following the steps i went though this forum. With week of using Ubuntu, I often came across 2 remarkable issues;

1. Whenever I save/modify a File/Folder using Windows 10 and switch to Ubuntu, the entire drive becomes VIEW only mode, cannot WRITE/MODIFY any thing in the drive. But, when I again relogin to Windows 10 and if i manually change ACCESS and then switch back to Ubuntu, I can fully access all drives. Every time I need to do this if I login to Windows 10 and come back to Ubuntu.
   [Note: I've 4 partitions in HDD in NTFS, and using the same partitions to save/access files/folders in Ubuntu]
2. Whenever I switch from Ubuntu to Windows 10 or vice versa, the TIME alone (DATE is getting updated to current date) is getting reset to GMT and not showing my local time even if I choose sync the Time Zone and update automatically option.

Do I need to reinstall Ubuntu or Is there any solution?

Kindly, guide me.

Comment: Log out and Shut down Windows, do not use sleep mode. In sleep mode windows is still "attached" to the file system. Make sure that your RTC is set to GMT and the OS'es obey that.

Comment: Depending on how Windows shut down (is "Fast Boot" off? Sometimes Windows leaves NTFS volumes in a "readable but invalid" state by using some closed-source Windows magic, and all Linux can do is mount it `ro` (Read Only). Find your drive in the output of `mount`.

Comment: @waltinator "Fast Startup" is the hybrid suspend option that must be disabled in Windows for a dual-boot configuration.  Fast Boot is actually something different and it's easy to confuse/conflate the two

Comment: @Nmath... Really thank you for your solution. After turning off "Fast Boot" my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to the time issue:

I would suggest having both operating systems manage the clock in hardware UTC mode. That way there will be no time zone or DST shenanigans.

On Ubuntu you can set this from the terminal by using:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

On Windows this is controlled by a registry setting:

https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time

You may also want to disable the windows time service if you run into problems after changing the above setting, as it may force set the hardware clock to a different time zone.

As per the comments on the drive access issue, if Windows is using "hybrid" shutdown, it is almost like hibernation, so Ubuntu will assume it is currently in use and not allow write access to prevent you from not being able to boot back into Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. After executing your recommended commands, my issue got rectified.